# Passport with TypeORM How to call typescript file from javascript?

Tags: sql-server, node.js, passport.js, typeorm

In our project we are using Nodejs, angular 1 and mongodb. For user login we are using Passport local strategy with mongoDB. Now we are migrating database to MSSQL so we are using TypeORM. TypeORM code is in Typescript. From NodeJS controller code i need to call Typescript code. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Typescript needs to be compiled to JavaScript before you can use it. TypeORM looks pretty awesome too.

**An example/suggestion of what you can do**

Create a `DataManager.ts` that will use `TypeORM` and do your work.

Read the Typescript docs really well. In `tsconfig.js` use the option `outDir` to specify the compiled output folder.

Run `tsc` command to compile the Typescript.

Now from you JavaScript part you can `require`  to use the generated files in the `outDir` that are in javaScript and use them.

To make your life easier and not have to run `tsc` and then `node app` commands all the time you can add in you npm start script `tsc && node app`

Comment: Thanks.. I tried the same.. I am getting the below error

Comment: > tsc && node server.js
node_modules/rxjs/Subject.d.ts(16,22): error TS2415: Class 'Subject<T>' incorrectly extends base class 'Observable<T>'.
  Types of property 'lift' are incompatible.
    Type '<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>) => Observable<T>' is not assignable to type '<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>) => Observable<R>'.
      Type 'Observable<T>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<R>'.
        Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'R'.
node_modules/typeorm/driver/mongodb/MongoConnectionOptions.d.ts(53,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Buffer'.

Comment: That irrelevant to your question and my answer. Your errors mean that you have compilation errors in Typescript. Try fixing your code and run `tsc` until it compiles with no errors and then run `node server.js`

Comment: I have resolved the above error.. thanks stamos.. now wen i am calling js files i am getting the below error.PostGetAllAction is the converted js file.                                        
    module.js:538
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'PostGetAllAction'

Comment: I have compiled the typescript file to javascript file and used require() function to refer to functions inside javascript file. it worked